# Database in Django framework

Tags: django-models

I started to learn Django framework. I can't understand how does it work OPM there. I mean, what kind of DBMS it uses?
How I understood, OPM is just interface between my Python-commands and DBMS-commands. And if I use MySQL, for example, I just should define it in Python and OPM will automatically interpret my Python-requiests to MySQL-command. Am I right?

Comment: I believe you meant ORM instead OPM. I am right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you meant ORM, you right!

Django ORM is a layer provided by the framework in between your application and Database(MySql, PostgreSql, Sqlite, etc). Rarely you will need to write SQL code directly to database, but on the other hand you will need to learn how to use ORM methods.
You can play with Django ORM in your shell - take a look. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/